# Intellij Ultimate: Javascript wildcard export results in "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

We have a dependency - `middle-dependency` - which re-exports another dependency - `base-dependency` - using a wildcard export, while also exporting its own members:

base-dependency:

```
export baseMember from './internal';
```

middle-dependency:

```
export * from 'base-dependency';
export middleMember from './internal';
```

Now, if we try to import `baseMember` from `base-dependency` via `middle-dependency`, IntelliJ autocomplete breaks and cannot find it. If we enter it manually, IntelliJ underlines it and complains about `cannot resolve symbol`.

Autocomplete works fine for the `middleMember` member. The code itself also compiles and runs fine.

```
import { middleMember, baseMember } from 'middle-dependency';
```

Is there any way to configure IntelliJ to make this work?